# StepArgumentTransformation is not getting hit

Tags: c#, regex, specflow

I have a scenario outline which contains scenarios which makes GET requests to a oData web API to get some data from it. Scenario
validate whether data returned from API is according to filters and in right order. Order by clause is built from table provided in the scenario

```
Scenario Outline: Validate that data from API call for a given user is according to filters provided
    
Given for the user id of 101
Given default filters for GET request
Given the result multicolumn order direction is <firstColumn> <firstOrderby> then <secondColumn> <secondOrderby>
And following is unordered list of securities
    
| securityID | attribute1 | attribute2 | attribute3 | attribute4 |
| 16654      | active     | 0          | pending    | 33         |
| 16655      | active     | 0          | pending    | 33         |
| 16656      | active     | 0          | pending    | 33         |
| 16657      | active     | 0          | pending    | 33         |
| 16658      | inactive   | 4          | pending    | 33         |
| 16659      | active     | 0          | pending    | 33         |
| 16660      | active     | 0          | pending    | 33         |
| 16661      | active     | 0          | pending    | 33         |
| 16662      | active     | 0          | pending    | 33         |
| 16663      | inactive   | 0          | pending    | 33         |
| 16664      | inactive   | 2          | pending    | 33         |
    
When I invoke the API GET
Then the SecAPI should return HTTP <statusCode>
And the response securities should be in expected order in each <sampleName> with matching fields and record count of 11

Examples:
    | firstColumn | firstOrderby | secondColumn | secondOrderby | statusCode | sampleName |
    | securityID  | Asc          | attribute2   | Desc          | 200        | Asc-Desc   |
    | securityID  | Asc          | attribute2   | Asc           | 200        | Asc-Asc    |
    | securityID  | Desc         | attribute2   | Asc           | 200        | Desc-Asc   |
    | securityID  | Asc          | attribute2   | Desc          | 200        | Asc-Desc   |
    | securityID  | Asc          | attribute2   |               | 200        | Asc-Desc   |
    | securityID  |              | attribute2   |               | 200        | Asc-Desc   |
```

For above scenario outline, all is working fine except below given statement:

```
Given the result multicolumn order direction is <firstColumn> <firstOrderby> then <secondColumn> <secondOrderby>
```

for above statement, I have below step in steps.cs file

```
[Given(@"the result multicolumn (order direction is (.*) (.*) then (.*) (.*))")]
public void GivenTheResultOrderDirectionIs(StringWrapper orderBy)
{
    //step code here
}
```

and following steptransformation to transform 4 arguments in given statement to proper oData orderBy clause:

```
[Binding]
public class CustomTransforms
{
    [StepArgumentTransformation(@"order direction is <(\w+)> <(\w+)> then <(\w+)> <(\w+)>")]
    public StringWrapper OrderByTransform(string column1, string column1Direction, string column2, string column2Direction)
    {
       string orderByClause;
       
       //build clause here

        return new StringWrapper(orderByClause);
    }

}
```

problem is OrderByClauseTransform is never called. I am getting below exception:

> Exception thrown: 'TechTalk.SpecFlow.BindingException' in TechTalk.SpecFlow.dll
> An exception of type 'TechTalk.SpecFlow.BindingException' occurred in TechTalk.SpecFlow.dll but was not handled in user code
> Parameter count mismatch! The binding method '.......GivenTheResultMulticolumnOrderDirectionIs(StringWrapper)' should have 5 parameters

Comment: `\w` does not match `<` nor `>`. You need `two column order is <(\w+)> <(\w+)> then <(\w+)> <(\w+)>`

Comment: Still not working. error is same that Given... method expects 5 parameters. it's not looking into transform method. if i remove extra () from given... method then error says it expects 4 parameters

Comment: Can you format your scenario outline and correct it? There are some formatting errors, so we are not sure if that is contributing to the problem.

Comment: I have reformatted and updated scenario outline. I am not allowed to post real code so this is mock up of the problem.

Comment: could it be that multiple arguments are not supported in SpecFlow transform?

Comment: I think @Sach is right. Step argument transforms take a single string argument. You'll need to split the pieces out that you need inside the method.

Comment: right. I think that is a good workaround for now. Multiple arguments in transform will be a good feature to add though

Comment: You don't really need multiple args. Just parse the string using the Regex you decorate the method with. You can separate the pieces from the single string.

Answer (score 0):

Step transformations only receive a single argument. That's just how SpecFlow works. Once you have the full matched string, use a `Regex` to extract the desired pieces from that string. By declaring a constant for the regex pattern, you can reuse that in a Regex object as well as the `[StepArgumentTransformation]` attribute:

```
[Binding]
public class CustomTransforms
{
    private const string OrderByPattern = @"order direction is (\w+) (\w+) then (\w+) (\w+)";

    private static readonly Regex OrderByRegex = new Regex(OrderByPattern);

    [StepArgumentTransformation(OrderByPattern)]
    public StringWrapper OrderByTransform(string text)
    {
        var match = OrderByRegex.Match(text);
        var column1 = match.Groups[1].Value;
        var direction1 = match.Groups[2].Value;
        var column2 = match.Groups[3].Value;
        var direction2 = match.Groups[4].Value;

        // Build your order by clause however you need to do it. For example, SQL:
        var orderByClause = $"ORDER BY {column1} {direction1}, {column2} {direction2}";

        return new StringWrapper(orderByClause);
    }
}
```

**Important:** The `<` and `>` characters in your step argument transformation pattern are also messing things up. In your scenario, the `<firstColumn>` token is completely replaced by the current value in the examples table.

When the current example row is:

```
| firstColumn | firstOrderby | secondColumn | secondOrderby | statusCode | sampleName |
| securityID  | Asc          | attribute2   | Desc          | 200        | Asc-Desc   |
```

The step:

```
Given the result multicolumn order direction is <firstColumn> <firstOrderby> then <secondColumn> <secondOrderby>
```

is converted to this automatically:

```
Given the result multicolumn order direction is securityID Asc then attribute2 Desc
```

Notice that the `<` and `>` characters do not exist in the converted version of the step. The angle brackets are used to denote parameterized portions of a step that are replaced at run time by data from the examples table.